# how to pass a knockout model to jsonresult parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I was trying to pass a whole object to the jsonresult method. but there are errors that occur. It might be the way I bound it but I'm not sure. I'm new to JS and KOJS. Once the Login button, which is bound to the LogUser method, is clicked, it should call the Authenticate(Employee p) method.

here is my class model

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public long AutoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    Display(Name = "Employee ID")]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string EmployeePassword { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}
```

this is my knockoutjs view model

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(LoginVm);
});

//VIEW MODEL. MODEL IS BELOW THIS
var LoginVm = {

    thisEmp: ko.observable(EmpObject),

    LogUser: function () {
        var self = this;

        //trying to check if thisEmp properties has values by alerting
        alert("ID: " + thisEmp.EmployeeId() + " Password: " + thisEmp.EmployeePassword());

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Employee/AuthenticateUser',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(thisEmp),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (errorMsg) {
                if (errorMsg === '') {

                }
            }
        });


    }
};

//MODEL
var EmpObject = {
    EmployeeId: ko.observable(''),
    EmployeePassword: ko.observable('')
}
```

this is my view and how I bound the properties

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeId, new { data_bind="value: thisEmp.EmployeeId()"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeePassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.EmployeePassword, new { data_bind="value: thisEmp.EmployeePassword()"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeePassword)
        </div>B

        <p>
            @*<input type="submit" value="Create"/>*@
            <input type="button" value="Login" data-bind="click: LogUser"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

this is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return thisEmp().EmployeeId }"
Message: Cannot read property 'EmployeeId' of undefined
    at value (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being thrown because you have defined `LoginVm` before`EmpObject`. You need to change the order they are declared.

Are you sure this is the code that produced this error? In your view you're binding `thisEmp.EmployeeId()` but th error says it's unable to bind `thisEmp().EmployeeId`. I think you tried both of them and the error still persisted. Either way, there is no need to make `thisEmp` an observable. It's enough that the properties are observables.

So, change your code to:

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new LoginVm());
});

//MODEL
var EmpObject = {
    EmployeeId: ko.observable(''),
    EmployeePassword: ko.observable('')
}

//VIEW MODEL. MODEL IS BELOW THIS
var LoginVm = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.thisEmp = EmpObject;

    self.LogUser = function () {
        var self = this;

        //trying to check if thisEmp properties has values by alerting
        alert("ID: " + self.thisEmp.EmployeeId() + " Password: " + self.thisEmp.EmployeePassword());

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Employee/AuthenticateUser',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(self.thisEmp),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (errorMsg) {
                if (errorMsg === '') {

                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And change the bindings in view to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeId, new { data_bind="value: thisEmp.EmployeeId"})
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.EmployeePassword, new { data_bind="value: thisEmp.EmployeePassword"})
```

Comment: what's the difference between var LoginVm = {} and var LoginVm = function(){}?

Comment: There are different ways of creating the object in javascript. What you're doing is the most common way of creating key-value pairs. It's called an object literal. I have created a `function` and using the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on it. This also creates an object. You can access the instance of the object(`self`) inside the `LogUser` method this way.

Comment: is there no pros and cons with var LoginVm = function(){}?

Comment: Creating a function and using the `new` keyword against it similar to how a `class` works in C#. Now you can create multiple `LoginVm` objects just by using `new LoginVm()`. I mean it;s not useful here. But when you have a table of objects, this is very useful